# SSMS reports - using a different Datasource than the server being reported against?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssms

I'd like to build a report in SSMS so that you can click on an object, choose the report, and it queries a data source (not the server you're looking at itself) to return information about that object.

All the SSMS reports I've seen use an empty data source (`Data Source=.`), so that SSMS runs it against whichever database/server/object you're clicking on.  I'm saving historical info on a different server.

I know it's possible; according to http://sqlbg.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/how-to-create-custom-reports-for-sql-server-management-studio/ there are 6 parameters passed.  I'd like to run a query against my data source, ideally passing those 6 parameters to an SP on my repository data source.

I took the code in the link above and created an RDL, then imported it into my project (SSDT and BIDS 2005 both; same issue).  It works in the Preview mode, returning a dataset from an Embedded Datasource in the report - but when I open the RDL in SSMS, I get "invalid object name "mytablename"' (where mytablename is the name of the table in my query).  So it looks like it's not properly using the data source.  Profiler confirms this - there's no login to the server at that time.

I have successfully reproduced the problem in SSDT and BIDS 2005 (8.0.50727.4039, Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Applications)

Many thanks!

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using (click help-about) and what version of BIDS?  (Let's go back to doing this with BIDS if you can - I don't know of people doing SSMS reports in SSDT, although it might be possible, but that's a tougher question.)

Comment: SSMS 2012 (11.0.2100.60), querying a SQL Server 2012.  I'm using SSDT, help-about shows Visual Studio 10.0.40219.1 SP1.  I'll try doing the same thing in BIDS 2005 (I saw a connect item saying that 2008 doesn't work in SSMS 2008).  Ran a profile trace and didn't see a connection, so it looks like it's the data source somehow.

Comment: @BrentOzar exact same issue in BIDS 2005.  Used the code from sqlbg (in main question) to create a template.  Created a local datasource in the project, got my query in Layout, added fields and it returns data in Preview.  Try opening it in SSMS and get "invalid object name" for the table I query, and Profiler doesn't show any connections to the server with the table.  Still thinking SSMS isn't liking the data source somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that SSMS will ONLY use the SQL Server you're clicking on as the data source, no matter what you actually use.  This is probably for security, but it makes cross-server reports more difficult.

To work around this, I created a linked server (RPC OUT on, collation compatible = true), using a specific user who only had read permissions.

If anyone knows of any cross-server reports that work in SSMS, please let me know - I'd love to know how they did it.